# Pathfinding algorithm

Tags: graph, path-finding

Given a directed graph, starting point, ending point and a time limit.
At each vertices, there's a "value" that represents how much attractive this location is. There's also a cost of traveling from vertices to another.

What i need is to find a path that is within the time limit and has the maximum "value".

Comment: Does the path permit repetition of vertices or edges?

Comment: nope. should not visit a vertices that is already visited

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for code golf-- you've given us no code you're having trouble with or a language to work in.

Comment: What i need is perhaps a suggestion on any algorithm i could use rather than a concrete solution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in part, note that the considered problem is `NP`-hard as it contains the [Knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem as a subproblem using the following reduction.

Given an instance of the Knapsack problem given by `n` items defined by profits `p_1,...,p_n` and weights `w_1,...,w_n` and a target capacity `C`, define a graph as follows.

To the left there is a source node `s` and a terminal node `t` to the right. For the `i`-th item define two nodes `yes_i` and `no_i`, which correspond to selecting and not selecting the respective item. The attractiveness of the `yes`-nodes is `p_i` and the attractiveness of the `no`-nodes is zero.

The pairs of nodes can be imagined as arranged in columns between the source and the terminal. Each node has in two in-edges from the previous column (except for the first colum, which is connected to the source). The weight of each of these edges is `w_i` if and only if they are the in-edges of a `yes`-node and zero if they are in-edges of a `no`-node. The last column is connected to the terminal.

Each path from `s` to `t` must column-wise decide whether or not to select the item of the respective colum; likewise, any selection of items corresponds to a path from `s` to `t`. By definition of the edge weights, the total weight of the path is equal to the total weight of the selection of items, while the total weight of the selected `yes`-nodes is equal to the the total weight of the selected items.

In total, we obtain a bijection of the feasible solutions of the Knapsack instance and the constructed instance of the described path problem. In total, this means that the problem in the question is `NP`-hard as it contains the Knapsack problem (which is known to be `NP`-hard) as a subproblem.

Alternatively the `NP`-hardness can be seen by setting the attractiveness of all locations in a complete graph to one; this special case of the problem is the decision version of the [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) problem, which is known to be `NP`-complete.